# Mocking browser history when testing action creators for React/Redux app using React-Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, jsdom, react-router-redux

In my React/Redux app built using `create-react-app` (which I have since ejected), I want to test some action creators that, in addition to some other things, call `browserHistory.push('/somePath`) from React Router v3 library (also using React-Router-Redux and Redux Thunk in my app).  I'm moving from using a mock store to using a real store, the benefits of which are discussed in [this article](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/2179).  However, with the current configuration, I get the following error when running the test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_history' of null
at Window.get history [as history] (/ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:151:79)
at /ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/BrowserProtocol.js:87:18
at updateLocation (/ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/BrowserProtocol.js:82:3)
at pushLocation (/ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/BrowserProtocol.js:86:10)
at /ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/createHistory.js:117:15
at /ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/createHistory.js:90:9
at next (/ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/AsyncUtils.js:51:7)
at loopAsync (/ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/AsyncUtils.js:55:3)
at confirmTransitionTo (/ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/createHistory.js:80:31)
at transitionTo (/ReactProjects/bp/node_modules/history/lib/createHistory.js:100:5)
```

From what I understand, `jsdom` is called when tests are run, but `jsdom` does not create anything related to browser history, hence the error message.

Has anyone run into a similar issue where they needed to mock browser history when testing action creators that invoke React Router methods?  If so, do you have any suggestions for this problem?  Thanks!